# Deriving antisymmetry of Lie bracket

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

[*P. Aluffi's "Algebra: Chapter ${\it 0}$"*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-104), (part of) exercise VI.$1.4.$

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $k$. A *Lie bracket* on $V$ is an operation $[\cdot,\cdot]\colon V\times V\to V$ such that
>
> - $(\forall u,v,w\in V),(\forall a,b\in k),~[au+bv,w]=a[u,w]+b[v,w],~[w,au+bv]=a[w,u]+b[w,v]$
> - $(\forall v\in V),~[v,v]=0$
> - and $(\forall u,v,w\in V),~[[u,v],w]+[[v,w],u]+[[w,u],v]=0$
>
> (This axiom is called the *Jacobi identity*). A vector space endowed with a Lie bracket is called a *Lie algebra*. $[\dots]$ Prove the following
>
> - In a Lie algebra $V$, $[u,v]=-[v,u]$ for all $u,v\in V$

As it appears Aluffi's definition is a bit unusual. After looking around I have seen Lie bracket commonly defined as antisymmetric. From here it follows easily that $[v,v]=0$ for all $v\in V$. Indeed, by the antisymmetry of the Lie bracket take $u=v$ and then $[v,v]=-[v,v]\implies 2[v,v]=0$. Thus $[v,v]=0$ for all $v\in V$ as desired.

Anyway, lets consider the listed axioms and try to derive antisymmetry. First off, note that $[v,0]=[0,v]=0$ for all $v\in V$ as $[v,0]=[v,0v]=0[v,v]=0$, by the first axiom, and similarly for $[0,v]$. Now, take the Jacobi identity with $v=w$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
[[v,w],w]+[[w,w],v]+[[w,v],w]&=0\\
[[v,w]+[w,v],w]+[0,v]&=0\\
[[v,w]+[w,v],w]&=0
\end{align*}
Now, if $w=0$ this holds trivially, so take $w\ne0$. Then either $[v,w]+[w,v]=0$ or $[v,w]+[w,v]=w$. But I was not able to derive a contradiction from the assumption that $[v,w]+[w,v]=w$ which would yield antisymmetry right away.

> Is it possible to finisht this attempt? If not, how would one approach proving the antisymmtery of the Lie bracket from the given axioms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the axioms we have
$$
0=[u+v,u+v]=[u,u]+[u,v]+[v,u]+[v,v]=[u,v]+[v,u]
$$
so that $[u,v]=-[v,u]$. Note that we do not need to use the Jacobi identity.

Comment: I see. I was thinking way too complicated then. Thank you kindly!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Note that the axiom $[v,v]=0$ avoids to use $2[v,v]=0$. This is important for Lie algebras of characteristic $2$, where $2=0$ so that we cannot conclude $[v,v]=0$ from $[v,u]=-[u,v]$. So Aluffi's definition is not so unusual.

Comment: Now I realise that I was sloppy at this point as I didn't thought of vector spaces over a field with characteristic $2$. Thanks for pointing out! I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to by the system :)